# Is it possible to put a callback to useReducer's dispatch in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const handleFilter = (filter_type, selection) => {
    dispatch({ type: filter_type, option: selection.option })
    filterData()
}
```

I have a `useReducer` that handles the selected filter. I have to call the `filterData` which filters the data based on the selected filter.

However, since it is not guaranteed for the `filterData` to occur after the dispatch, I keep getting delayed update in the state.

I also tried

```
const handleFilter = (filter_type, selection) => {
    dispatch({ type: filter_type, option: selection.option })
    .then(filterData())
}
```

But this gave me an error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Any help?

**EDIT**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const urls = [
        'http://.../v1/profiles',
    ];
    const fetchJson = url => fetch(url, get_options).then(res => res.json());
    Promise.all(urls.map(fetchJson))
        .then(([profile]) => {
            setFilteredTable(profile.result)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
}, []);

const init_filter = { TITLE: '', LOCATION: '' }

const [filter, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TITLE':
            return { ...state, TITLE: action.option }
        case 'LOCATION':
            return { ...state, LOCATION: action.option }
        case 'RESET':
            return init_filter
        default:
            return state
    }
}, init_filter)
```

Comment: You can't just add `then` to a function and wish for a result

Comment: Can you not call filterdata in the reducer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I have to **call** the `filterData` which filters the data **based on** the selected filter.

You describing a listener, you can try using a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook:

```
const [filter, dispatch] = useReducer(optionsReducer, initialValue);

useEffect(() => {
  filterData();
}, [filter]);

const handleFilter = (filter_type, selection) => {
  dispatch({ type: filter_type, option: selection.option });
};
```

Comment: Can you check my edit plz? I use `useEffect` to fetch data from db. I am not sure how to make it work only for changes in the filter.

Comment: You can use multiple `useEffect`s, the above listener runs on `filter` change, try reading the docs.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know multiple `useEffects` were possible. It works now. Thanks!